# CKAN package group permissions

Tags: permissions, package, ckan, usergroups

How can I change the permissions in CKAN, so every editor/admin of an organization can add a group to a dataset (right now, the editor or admin has to be a member of the group to be able to add a certain group to a dataset)?

The dataportal I am developing only has 8 groups and every admin/editor should be able to add these groups to a dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that Group permissions are a bit of a hangover from the past (there was a time in CKAN without Organizations and only groups, and groups are based heavily on Organizations internally) and I wanted to make a proposal to the CKAN developers for providing an option to remove them (i.e. every Org editor or Admin can add anything to any group). Apart from that possibility there are a couple of workarounds:

- Make everyone of these users a superuser (probably bad)
- Make a "master" group which contains all existing groups (this is only
  possible via the API) and then use the cascading authorization
  configuration:
  http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/configuration.html#ckan-auth-roles-that-cascade-to-sub-groups
- Make an extension that hooks into the user creation process and
  automatically adds all Org editors and Admins to all groups
- Make an
  extension that doesn't check or relaxes auth when trying to add
  datasets to groups (this seems like overkill compared to the general
  change I mentioned at the beginning: both would need to be coded and
  I am more interested in doing the first one!)